# Open open url on default browser with Basic Authentication

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I trying to open a web version from the app but I wanted to allow the user to avoid to have to login again. Is there a way that I can send the user's credentials or send a http header on the intent. The page I'm trying to open uses basic authentication.

so far what i have:

```
String url = "https://" + userManagementPageURL;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
activity.startActivity(i);
```

I don't control the server that i'm trying to access so i can't make/request any modification to it.

Is what i'm trying possible? Is there any possible alternative?
Thanks for any help, this is driving me insane.

Comment: Did you try using `https://username:password@example.com/some/uri?with=parameters` as URL? Not sure if the usual android browsers support that (thus no answer). Also, this may cause the password to be cached in the browser's history.

Comment: yes i have tried that, but i still get redirected to the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can call the url from a web view. Then catch the response from the server after login, store response in a shared preference, and check the shared preference when logging in again.